# Is there any way to display the package contents using `apt-get` without first downloading the package?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, packaging

I know I can list the files in a package using the following command, which first download the package (.deb) into `/var/cache/apt/archives` and then list its contents:

```
apt-get --download-only install <pkg>
dpkg --contents <pkg> (.deb)
```

Does `apt-get` support any way of listing the package contents without first downloading the package?

**Extra**: Furthermore, how can I download a package using `apt-get --download-only ...` without all of its dependencies?

Comment: You can also search for some distributions on [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/) which will list the filenames.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that `apt-get` can do it, no, but `apt-file` can:

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt update
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-file list <pkg>
```

For example:

```
$ sudo apt-file list xterm
xterm: /etc/X11/app-defaults/KOI8RXTerm
xterm: /etc/X11/app-defaults/KOI8RXTerm-color
xterm: /etc/X11/app-defaults/UXTerm
xterm: /etc/X11/app-defaults/UXTerm-color
xterm: /etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm
xterm: /etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm-color
xterm: /usr/bin/koi8rxterm
xterm: /usr/bin/lxterm
xterm: /usr/bin/resize
xterm: /usr/bin/uxterm
xterm: /usr/bin/xterm
xterm: /usr/share/applications/debian-uxterm.desktop
xterm: /usr/share/applications/debian-xterm.desktop
xterm: /usr/share/doc-base/xterm-ctlseqs
xterm: /usr/share/doc-base/xterm-faq
xterm: /usr/share/doc/xterm/NEWS.Debian.gz
xterm: /usr/share/doc/xterm/README.Debian
xterm: /usr/share/doc/xterm/README.i18n.gz
xterm: /usr/share/doc/xterm/changelog.Debian.gz
xterm: /usr/share/doc/xterm/copyright
xterm: /usr/share/doc/xterm/ctlseqs.ms.gz
xterm: /usr/share/doc/xterm/ctlseqs.txt.gz
xterm: /usr/share/doc/xterm/xterm.faq.gz
xterm: /usr/share/doc/xterm/xterm.faq.html
xterm: /usr/share/doc/xterm/xterm.log.html
xterm: /usr/share/doc/xterm/xterm.termcap.gz
xterm: /usr/share/doc/xterm/xterm.terminfo.gz
xterm: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/xterm-color.png
xterm: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/xterm-color.svg
xterm: /usr/share/man/man1/koi8rxterm.1.gz
xterm: /usr/share/man/man1/lxterm.1.gz
xterm: /usr/share/man/man1/resize.1.gz
xterm: /usr/share/man/man1/uxterm.1.gz
xterm: /usr/share/man/man1/xterm.1.gz
xterm: /usr/share/pixmaps/filled-xterm_32x32.xpm
xterm: /usr/share/pixmaps/filled-xterm_48x48.xpm
xterm: /usr/share/pixmaps/mini.xterm_32x32.xpm
xterm: /usr/share/pixmaps/mini.xterm_48x48.xpm
xterm: /usr/share/pixmaps/xterm-color_32x32.xpm
xterm: /usr/share/pixmaps/xterm-color_48x48.xpm
xterm: /usr/share/pixmaps/xterm_32x32.xpm
xterm: /usr/share/pixmaps/xterm_48x48.xpm
```

As for downloading, that's what the `download` command is for:

```
apt-get download <pkg>
```

See `man apt-get`:

```
   download
       download will download the given binary package into the current
       directory.
```

Comment: Thank you, @terdon. Do you know how `apt-file` works? Does it download the package locally before running `dpkg --contents`, or does it consult some online resource? Is it developed by the developers of APT or someone else?

Comment: why would I use `apt-get --download-only install`, when `apt-get download` is available? Is it only because the former will also download dependencies (and put them all in `/var/cache/apt/archives`), while the latter will **only** download the specified package without dependencies into the current directory?

Comment: `apt-file` works by downloading a `Contents` file from the Debian/Ubuntu/etc. repository.